# Why does the bordism category have duals?

Tags: higher-category-theory, smooth-manifolds, topological-quantum-field-theory, cobordism, extended-tqft

The proof of the Cobordism Hypothesis outlined by Lurie seems to assume that the $(\infty, n)$-category $\mathbf{Bord}_n^{(X, \zeta)}$ has duals, i.e. duals for objects and adjoints for all $k$-morphisms $(1\leq k < n)$. The example given is for the oriented category, where the left and right adjoint of $M:X\to Y$ is given by the same manifold with opposite orientation $\overline{M}:Y\to X$.

(1) How do you actually prove that $\overline{M}$ is an adjoint to $M$?

(2) Considering the framed bordism category suggests that the general case is a bit more subtle. How does the above argument generalize to $\mathbf{Bord}_n^{(X, \zeta)}$?